# Symfony2 custom user provider not authenticating/logging in

Tags: php, symfony

I have a custom user provider called CustomUserProvider, which I use to manage the logins. The problem I've been having, is that it doesn't authenticate/login the user - it refreshes the page and nothing happens.

I even followed it through, to see if it's getting into the loadUserByUsername method, and it was. `$userData` gets populated with the correct user, and it should be returning it. To take it 1 step further, I even setup a custom authenticator as well, to make sure that the token was getting generated properly - even with that, it wasn't logging them in - just refreshing the page, and nothing actually happening.

Here's the `loadUserByUsername` snippet from `CustomUserProvider`.

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{            
        // query database and do the custom salt/password check
        $userData = $this->em->createQuery(
            '....'
        )->setParameter('username', $username)
         ->getResult();

        if (count($userData) > 0) {

            return $userData[0];
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
            );
        }

}
```

And here's my `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext        
        Project\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\Accounts: sha512

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [my_fos_facebook_provider, custom_provider]
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user
        custom_provider:
            id: custom_user_provider

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/sendioso-dev/"
                server_url: "http://www.website.com/facebookApp/"
                login_path: _security_login
                check_path: _security_check
                default_target_path: /
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            form_login:
                login_path:  project_main_login
                check_path:  project_main_login_check
                provider: custom_provider
            logout:
                path:        project_main_logout
            anonymous: ~
            #simple_preauth:
            #    authenticator: custom_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

*** UPDATE ***

I was checking `dev.log` and this came up:

```
[2014-02-21 21:39:40] security.INFO: User "email@email.com" has been authenticated successfully [] []
```

So it looks like it's somewhat working, but it doesn't actually log me in - just refreshes the page and that's it.

*** UPDATE 2 ***

I did some more digging, and found out that it's passing an account object with all NULL values, when calling `refreshUser(UserInterface $user)` in `CustomUserProvider`.

Anyone know why it would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

When it was serializing the 'Accounts' object, it wasn't persisting the data in the serialization. So, whenever it deserialized, it made everything NULL.

I went into the Entity and fixed the way it did the serialization, so now it persists the columns that I need for this to work.